# Reset index on multilevel columns in pandas so that higher index perfaces lower index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like:

```
df   a       b
     c   d   e  f 
1    .   .   .  .
2    .   .   .  .
3    .   .   .  .
4    .   .   .  .
```

and want this as the result:

```
 df  
       ac   ad  be  bf 
    1    .   .   .  .
    2    .   .   .  .
    3    .   .   .  .
    4    .   .   .  .
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`df.columns.map("".join)` is enough, as following:

```
In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
   A        B      
   C  D  E  F  G  H
0  0  1  2  3  4  5
1  0  1  2  3  4  5
2  0  1  2  3  4  5
3  0  1  2  3  4  5
4  0  1  2  3  4  5
5  0  1  2  3  4  5

In [13]: df.columns = df.columns.map("".join)

In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
   AC  AD  AE  BF  BG  BH
0   0   1   2   3   4   5
1   0   1   2   3   4   5
2   0   1   2   3   4   5
3   0   1   2   3   4   5
4   0   1   2   3   4   5
5   0   1   2   3   4   5
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use map and a zip/join over the column levels:

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
   a     b
   c  d  e  f
1  .  .  .  .
2  .  .  .  .
3  .  .  .  .
4  .  .  .  .

In [12]: df.columns.map(lambda x: "".join(*zip(*x)))
Out[12]: array(['ac', 'ad', 'be', 'bf'], dtype=object)

In [13]: df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: "".join(*zip(*x)))

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
  ac ad be bf
1  .  .  .  .
2  .  .  .  .
3  .  .  .  .
4  .  .  .  .
```

Comment: Gives me this error: "TypeError: join() takes exactly one argument (2 given"

Comment: @robertevansanders the \*s are important.

Comment: I was just copy pasting your code so I did use them

Comment: @robertevansanders hmmm, maybe python2 doesn't allow the multi-argument join, try  `"".join(zip(*x))`

Comment: That gives this error: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, tuple found

Comment: @robertevansanders let me just check in py2.

Comment: @robertevansanders this work for me in python 2.7. What python version are you using?

Comment: I am also using 2.7! :(

Comment: amazingly this also works in python 2.6. So I'm a little confused here.

Comment: Try `df.columns.map(lambda x: "".join(list(*zip(*x))))` but I don't see why the above doesn't work (like I say, I've tried in 3.4, 2.7.10 and 2.6.9). All working! :s

Comment: Ugh!
TypeError: list() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: can you do `import sys; sys.version` what version exactly do you have?

Comment: 2.7.6    version is the python

Comment: Hmmm, I can't reproduce on that either. What's the output of `df.columns.map(lambda x: zip(*x))` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94889/discussion-between-robertevansanders-and-andy-hayden).